# matlab sort one column and keep respective values on second column

Tags: matlab, sorting, row

How do I just do a simple sort in matlab. I always have to use the excel link to import my data, sort it, then export back to matlab. This is annoying!!!

I have one matrix <10x10> and I want to sort the first column in descending order while keeping it's respective values on the second column. Matlab seems to just sort each column individually.

```
Example:
matrix a
5 4
8 9
0 6
7 3

matrix b (output)
0 6
5 4
7 3
8 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `b=sortrows(a);` See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html).

Answer (score 10):

The `sortrows` answer by @chaohuang is probably what you're looking for.  However, it sorts based on all columns.  If you only want to sort based on the first column, then you can do this:

```
% sort only the first column, return indices of the sort
[~,sorted_inds] = sort( a(:,1) );

% reorder the rows based on the sorted indices
b = a(sorted_inds,:);
```